# Collapse each div separately in C# MVC Razor foreach loop

Tags: javascript, c#, css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I'm working on C# mvc project, and I'm trying to load product cart partial view, where I want in each row to have a button Read More for product specification. When users click on Read more it should collapse in div where specification for product are loaded.
I manage to accomplish this by creating css style for div Id - product-intro, but It functioning just on first row.
I'm now trying to dynamically create div Id's and also style inline product-intro"+"-"+i and I cant manage working.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Here is my html:

```
    @{int i = 0;}

@foreach (var line in Model.Lines)
{
    var validQuantityClass = line.Quantity <= line.InStock ? "" : "danger";
    <tr class="article @validQuantityClass" id="article-@line.Product.ProductId">
        <td>
            <div class="media">

                <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">@line.Product.Name</h4>

                @{i++;}

                <script>articleSpec()</script>

                <div class="media-body">
                    <div id="@("product-intro"+"-"+i)" class="collapse" style="margin-bottom: 10px; border-bottom:1px solid #dee2e6; padding:10px 0; font-size: 12px;">
                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                            <div class="col">
                                <span id='@string.Format("article-{0}-spec", line.Product.tecId)'></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#product-intro-@i">Read More +</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function articleSpec() {

        $("#product-intro").each(function (index) {
            var articleId = document.getElementById('tecId').value;
            if (!articleId)
                return;

            var labelSelector = "#article-" + articleId + "-spec";

            var url = "/Search/ArticleSpecification";
            var postdata = "articleid=" + articleId;

            $.post(url,
                postdata,
                function (data) {
                    $(labelSelector).html(data);
                });
        });
    }
</script>
```

And this is my css for product-intro:

```
.cart-content #product-intro {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I also tried to pass @i in javascript and dynamically load data in div:

```
function articleSpec(number) {

        $("#product-intro" + '-' + number).each(function (index) {
```